# Understanding a double peaked distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, monte-carlo

I am running a Monte Carlo Simulation and am sampling randomly from about 65 Normal Distributions, each with a different $\mu$ and $\sigma$. I end up with the Mixture Distribution graph shown below amd trying to evaluate the cause of the 2nd peak. The plot appears to be on the way to becoming bi-modal, with increased iterations *possibly*. Will it be worth trying to evaluate the cause of the modes as is mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Modes)?

Image:
[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: Almost all mixtures of normal distributions will give a  distribution with multiple local maxima, though extensive sampling would be needed to resolve all the peaks.  In your example, it would seem that most of the $\mu_i$ are clustered around one value and a few clustered around another value, and yes, lots more sampling will likely give more local peaks; indeed, even the main peak might resolve into two narrower peaks, etc.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thank you very much. I shall try increasing the number of iterations of my MC simulation and see what results are obtained.